# Is it possible to use workmanager in Flutter to relaunch the app after a few hours (depending on the situation) when the app is completely closed?

Tags: flutter, android-workmanager

I want to create an app that shows an alarm screen that sounds when the app is restarted when certain conditions are met after communicating with the api using workmanager in Flutter. However, the app does not restart even if I use the code below.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    do{
    code that api communication....
    }while(When conditions are satisfied)
    
    Restart.restartApp();//When I try to relaunch the app, nothing happens
    });

    return Future.value(true);
  
}
```

Comment: Just in terms of user experience, don't you think if an app automatically opened after performing a background task would creep a user out? If I was the user I would have removed the app in an instant. So, you can just show a notification when background task was successful and if the user clicks the notification the app would open up. You can use clickbait notification if you want to.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin agreed, only system apps are allowed to do this kind of stuff in past but now you can only saw notification with custom sound and customized buttons.